# trying to understand if/else loops combined with functions

Tags: javascript, function, loops

so I am trying to create a function with two parameters. This function will be passed with two numbers as arguments. calculate the sum of the parameters. If the sum is less than or equal to 25, the function should return true. If not it should return false. 
I know I must use a if and else loop to check the parameters (or a ternary which we have not covered yet.) This is what I have gotten so far. Please tell me if I am on the right track or completely wrong.

```js
function sum(augment1,augment2) {
   var num= augment1 + augment2;
   return num;
}
        
var a=sum(10,30)
console.log(a);
         
if (num > 25) {
   return true
}
else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Some indentation would help.

Comment: Where's the function you are returning from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions should be inside your function right?  So if the sum is less than or equal to 25 return true else return false. Can you try following?

```
function sum(augment1, augment2) {
  var num = augment1 + augment2;
  if (num <= 25) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

var a = sum(10, 30)
console.log(a); // should be false
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I finally understand how this works... Real AHA moment just now lol.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, can you fix the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use an if-else statement - the `<=` operator returns a boolean result, so you could just return it:

```
function isSumEqualOrLessThan25(augment1, augment2) {
    var sum = augment1 + augment2;
    return sum <= 25;
}
```